# on change select spinner data change want to set on another spinner...how to do?

Tags: android

I have two spinner court and judge. I want to on select court spinner data judge change acc to courtid.

```
private void loadSpinnerDataCourt() {
    Spinner spinnercourt = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnercourt);
    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    // Spinner Drop down elements
    List<String> lables = db.getAllCourt();

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnercourt.setAdapter(dataAdapter);
    //loadSpinnerDataCourt();

}
```

This is judge spinner

```
 private void loadSpinnerDataJudge() {
    Spinner spinnerjudge = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinnerjudge);

    // database handler
    DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

    String room4 = Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner4.label4;
    int idcourt = Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner4.idcourt;
    // Spinner Drop down elements pass court id
    List<String> lables = db.getAlljudge(idcourt);

    // Creating adapter for spinner
    ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
            android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);

    // Drop down layout style - list view with radio button
    dataAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

    // attaching data adapter to spinner
    spinnerjudge.setAdapter(dataAdapter);


}
```

But how to call this judge spinner on change court spinner. Select 1st data of court then pass that id on this judge spinner and then give judge name under that court. How to call this judge spinner on change court?

Answer (score 1):

Implement this method

```
spinnercourt.setOnItemSelectedListener(new OnItemSelectedListener() {

        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                int arg2, long arg3) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            loadSpinnerDataJudge()
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        }
    })
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: i am using like dis bt got error in loadSpinnerDataJudge() dis method calling public static class Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner4 implements OnItemSelectedListener 
    {
    public static int idcourt;  
 public static String label4;

 public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position,
   long id) {
  // On selecting a spinner item
  label4 = parent.getItemAtPosition(position).toString();

   loadSpinnerDataJudge();
 }

 

 @Override
 public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> arg0) {
  // TODO Auto-generated method stub
  
 }
    } hw to solve?? help me

Comment: using like ur suggestion bt calling loadSpinnerDataJudge() method got error........hw to solve it?

Comment: i.e because you can not call static parameters in the private method. For that you have to solve that issue.

Comment: in loadSpinnerDataJudge() need value of label4..den hw to access label4?? if non use Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner4 this class as a non static den label4 is not accessible outside d class....i need d value of label4 in method loadSpinnerDataJudge....wht to do??

Comment: public void loadSpinnerDataJudge() {   String room4 = Listener_Of_Selecting_Room_Spinner4.label4;.......} need dis label4 value

Comment: store that value in preference.

Comment: how to store value in preference??

Comment: http://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/content/android-sharedpreferences-example/

Answer (score 0):

Implement a setOnItemSelectedListener

[set onClickListener for spinner item?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12108893/set-onclicklistener-for-spinner-item)
[Android: How to make selected spinner item to TextView?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15759403/android-how-to-make-selected-spinner-item-to-textview)
[Android: two Spinner onItemSelected()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9262871/android-two-spinner-onitemselected)
http://www.mkyong.com/android/android-spinner-drop-down-list-example/

Answer (score 0):

please use `setOnItemSelectedListener` of your court spinner. and its `onItemSelected` method set the list of judge list according to court item selection.

Comment: onItemSelected method calling loadSpinnerDataJudge() dis method bt got error...hw to solve?

Comment: what is the code on loadSpinnerDataJudge() method ? Your simply modify your judge list in this method.. Don't do anything else on this method..

Comment: see above loadSpinnerDataJudge() i m using dis method inside onItemSelected on court...bt got error...

Comment: actually judge list also on d basis on court id den pass dis court id and got list of judge and den set on judge spinner..